# Test ASP.NET on local server

Tags: asp.net

How could I test ASPX.NET web application in a local server? What do I need to install? Sorry guys, just a newbie. I've been done some searches also but I always failed. I've encountered a what so called IIS Server but, I can't barely get it. Hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Within Visual Studio, did you tried to press F5?

Comment: install first or configure your IIS first

Comment: if you are using Visual Studio, you can test your app as what @SteveB said

Comment: Yes, I can make it run in VS but what I need is, I want to try it also in another computer, so, do I need also to install VS to the other machine for it to run? I mean is, maybe there are ways in which we can run it just like in php, by just typing localhost to the browser's url field.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a requirement. But if you want to test ASP.Net, you are testing a programming language, which implies having a descent development environment.

Answer (score 2):

As other said, IIS is part of the operating system (either in Windows server OS, or professional edition of Windows XP/Vista/7).

You can also fall back to [IIS express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038) which allows you to run apps locally, with the logged user's identity.

This will be enough to run any asp.net web apps (with limitations like number of simultaneous connections, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need server application IIS if you want test on local, you have Cassini server , if you use Framework 2.0 or more, he is installed on your runtime by defaut

Answer (score 1):

the IIS server installation comes with windows installation. You can not get it separately. It is a part of windows server installation. You can install it from add/remove windows components section of control panel.

Further, there are many other web servers that can be used for it. e.g. cassini web server (which is also available with visual studio)

Comment: Actually, you can install IIS Express, which is a separate installation. It's free, and runs under the user's account instead of a system service. Can be useful in restricted scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Like for PHP you need something on your machine to serve PHP pages, e.g WAMP server, similarly you have to set up the machine to serve asp.net pages. As WAMP for PHP, install IIS for ASP.NET. You need to check some MSDN on web deployment. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

try to write in `Run...` option(click Start/Run...)
`inetmgr` this command (If you have IIS Express or full version of IIS) will show you IIS server manager.

In manager you will see at right column name of your computer click `plus` sign on the left.
Then Right click `Sites` and choose `Add Web Site...`

You will need to write name of website, provide path to your project (folder which contains web.config), and change port

after this you need to check `Application pool` (it's name will be same that your website)  for your website and if you use .NET Framework version 4 you will need to change (default version of framework is 2.0)

**Edit:**
Next step to test app on IIS (with debug functionality) is:

- right click on project solution in Visual Studio (Solution navigator) and choose properties
- choose Web bookmark on the left side
- in section `Servers` check radiobutton near Use Local IIS Web Server
- in textBox below with (Project Url:) write `http:/localhost: port which you wrote in IIS when creating website

and That's all you need to do :) From now you can Test your project localy on IIS:)

Hope this will help:)